# Problems with filtering data in Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a post, and the question is that i need to filter a list with the users who have published the most posts. I had tried, but only managed to filter the total posts, and have had trouble with that.

The fields in `Models.py` from User:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
    
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        creation_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        description = models.TextField()
        avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='autores/', default='img/default.jpg')
        social = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
        is_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

meanwhile in `models.py` from Blog:

```
class Post(ModeloBase):
    title = models.CharField('Titulo del Post', max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField('Descripcion')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    content= RichTextField()
    referential_img = models.ImageField('Imagen Referencial', upload_to='imagenes/', max_length=255)
    published= models.BooleanField('Publicado / No Publicado', default=False)
    publication_date = models.DateField('Fecha de Publicacion')
    like = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='likes')
    dislike = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, blank=True, related_name='dislikes')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Looking in the django documentation, i tried to do the filtering but it didn't work for me. I don't know what my mistake was, so i hope someone could help me.

for example, so i have my structure to get recent posts by category:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = 'home.html'
        post_general = Post.objects.filter(state= True, published= True, category= Category.objects.get(name='General')).order_by('publication_date')

        context = {
            'post_general': post_general,
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to get the user with the most posts made?

Comment: no, I want it to show something like a top of the number of users with more posts.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
Usuario.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('post')).order_by('-num_post')
```

If that does not answer your question properly (I had some problem understanding it), please refer to the django doc page on [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by). This is where you want to read about your goal.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I try to verify if I can, otherwise I will read the documentation of Aggregation.